# How to return Response 401 in Jersey with json content

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

I am trying to return UNAUTHORIZED response with json content in one of my REST method. I am using Jersey 2.5.1 with Spring.

I am using following annotations on my method:

```
@Path("login")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response myMethod(@Valid CmdObject cmd) {
  ...
  return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).entity(AUTHENTICATION_ERROR_MSG).build();
}
```

In case if AUTHENTICATION_ERROR_MSG is just a String for example "Authentication problem" everything is fine and a response is returned however it is String content only.

In case if I replace AUTHENTICATION_ERROR_MSG with some Object then 500 Http error is returned.

Any suggestion what may be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When the server returns error 500, what error message does it return?

Do you already have other methods that correctly return JSON?

Notat that you need to add a library that provides Jersey with the ability to convert an object into JSON. Otherwise, it cannot convert an object into JSON.

According to [Jersey's user guide](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#json.moxy), the preferred library to do this is MOXy. Add the following to the `pom.xml`of your project if you want to use that.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
</dependency>
```